# Getting Error after converting mysql query to postgresql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

> $ Customer.send("today").count

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers" WHERE (`customers`.created_at >
 '2014-02-07 05:00:00.000000')


 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error
 at or near "."
     LINE 1: ...LECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers"  WHERE (`customers`.created_at > '2014-02-07 05:00:00.000000')
```

When I convert my MYSQL database to PG then I m getting this error how can I fix this. If I right this query in MySQL then it's working fine but in PG getting error.

Help me Please...!

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks for quoting is a MySQL-ism, standard SQL and PostgreSQL use double quotes for quoting identifiers. Somewhere you have:

```
where('`customers`.created_at > ?', something)
```

but PostgreSQL wants to see:

```
where('"customers".created_at > ?', something)
```

However, since the table name is lower case and not a reserved word, you can drop the quotes and get something that is both easier to read and will work in both databases:

```
where('customers.created_at > ?', something)
```

Presumably this change needs to be made inside the `send` scope.